# How to overlay div above html form?

Tags: html, css, forms, loading

I want to display an animated loading icon when the user have submitted a search.

SEQUENCE OF EVENTS I'M LOOKING FOR:

- USER SUBMITTED A SEARCH
- MAKE LOADING ICON VISIBLE
- MAKE LOADING ICON INVISIBLE ONCE THE SEARCH IS COMPLETED

The issue I'm facing is mostly css.

- Firstly, the loading icon seems to be behind the form element.
- Secondly, I cannot increase the size of the div (searchEngineForm) to have the same size as the form.
- Lastly, I cannot set div (searchEngineForm) width to 100%. It goes outside of the form.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="setJobFields" method="POST">
   <div id="searchEngineForm" style="display: none;">
      <div class="loader">
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#searchEngineForm{
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 100%; */
}
.loader {
    
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[image: DEMO]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an html element above others, you could set its Z-index to a higher number than what’s around it.

For example, say you’re wanting to display your loading symbol in front of the rest of the page. You could contain the whole page in a single div, for the sake argument we give it a class of “page”, we can set it as:

```
.page{ z-index: -1 ;}
```

And the loader as

```
.loader{ z-index: 1; }
```

Then, to position it where you want, you can set the position to absolute and move it around with the top and left properties, such as

```
.loader{ z-index:1; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. :D